# Converting shapefile labels to graphics ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, convert, contour, annotation

I have a `shapefile` that represents `contours`. Because I have `clipped` the contours to the map boundary they are broken in several places. Now that I have `labeled` the contours there are labels that are repeated for the same value, for example, the `0.1` contour interval is broken is several places and the label `0.1` is repeated. I would like to `convert` my `labels` to `graphics` so that I can delete the undesired labels.

How do I do this in `ArcMap 10`?

[image]

Comment: Do you have Maplex? If so the duplicates may be handled dynamically. If not then @PolyGeo provided the solution below.

Comment: I do not have Maplex.

Comment: Once you are using 10.1 you will have access to Maplex which has become standard with all license levels of ArcGIS for Desktop: http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/maplex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to [Convert Labels To Annotation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000m0000000q000000).

Once they are annotations (which are like "graphics" for labels) you can select and delete any you want within an edit session.

Comment: Does it matter whether the annotation is stored in the database or the map?

Comment: Since you were looking for "graphics" then maybe storing them in the map would fit better.  However, if you are already comfortable with geodatabases then that is the way I would go.